RDS - Web Client Issue - Separate Gateway/Broker and Virtualization Host (not a session host)
So I've run into an issue with deploying the Web Client. Initially when we set up the VDI system we had EVERYTHING running on the same server as a demo, and the web client functioned flawlessly.
Since then we've split it into separate Gateway/Broker and a beefier Virtualization Host and now I get the error "your session ended because an unexpected server authentication certificate was received from the remote pc"
I thought this would function the same way, I export the certificate from the connection broker that is hosting the web client management/broker/gateway and import in for the Web Client like this:
Import-RDWebClientBrokerCert C:\RDBrokerCert.cer
but it's not functioning.
By Remote PC is it referring to the virtualization host? I could have sworn it doesn't care about that but maybe it does? Obviously it has a different certificate than the one on the broker, but that certificate was issued by our CA and it's trusted. Is there a log I can look at to see what certificate it's complaining about?
I followed the standard troubleshooting for the error, verify the web access certificate and the certificate that was imported to the web client are the same, looks good to me, same fingerprint. Ensured that the server FQDN is in the CN AND the subject alt names. I'm at a loss as to what else it could be.
I confirmed that using the actual RDP file works so clients will at least have that access but I'd really like to get the Web Client up and running because some of the employees prefer the slicker interface.
